# I am trying to create_all() for a postgresql table but i am getting weird errors

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

My python flask code (quotes.py) is :

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql+psycopg2:// postgres:password@localhost/quotes'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Favquotes(db.Model):

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    author = db.Column(db.String(30))
    quote = db.Column(db.String(2000))

@app.route('/')
def index():
    result = Favquotes.query.all()
    return render_template('index.html', result = result)



@app.route('/quotes')
def quotes():
    return render_template('quotes.html')

@app.route('/process', methods = ['POST'])
def process():
    author = request.form['author']
    quote = request.form['quote']
    quotedata = Favquotes(author = author , quote = quote)
    db.session.add(quotedata)
    db.session.commit()
    return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

Getting the following errors :

```
>>> from quotes import db
>>> db.create_all()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\KIIT\Desktop\fav-quotes\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 3250, in _wrap_pool_connect
    return fn()
  File "C:\Users\KIIT\Desktop\fav-quotes\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 310, in connect
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
  File "C:\Users\KIIT\Desktop\fav-quotes\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 868, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
  File "C:\Users\KIIT\Desktop\fav-quotes\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 476, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
  File "C:\Users\KIIT\Desktop\fav-quotes\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\impl.py", line 146, in _do_get
    self._dec_overflow()
  File "C:\Users\KIIT\Desktop\fav-quotes\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 70, in __exit__
    compat.raise_(
  File "C:\Users\KIIT\Desktop\fav-quotes\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 207, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "C:\Users\KIIT\Desktop\fav-quotes\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\impl.py", line 143, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
  File "C:\Users\KIIT\Desktop\fav-quotes\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 256, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
  File "C:\Users\KIIT\Desktop\fav-quotes\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 371, in __init__
    self.__connect()
  File "C:\Users\KIIT\Desktop\fav-quotes\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 666, in __connect
    pool.logger.debug("Error on connect(): %s", e)
  File "C:\Users\KIIT\Desktop\fav-quotes\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 70, in __exit__
    compat.raise_(
  File "C:\Users\KIIT\Desktop\fav-quotes\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 207, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "C:\Users\KIIT\Desktop\fav-quotes\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 661, in __connect
    self.dbapi_connection = connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
  File "C:\Users\KIIT\Desktop\fav-quotes\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\create.py", line 590, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "C:\Users\KIIT\Desktop\fav-quotes\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 597, in connect
    return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "C:\Users\KIIT\Desktop\fav-quotes\venv\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user " postgres"
```

my pip list contain :

```
(venv) PS C:\Users\KIIT\Desktop\fav-quotes> pip list
Package          Version
---------------- -------
 - click            8.0.3
 - colorama         0.4.4
 - Flask            2.0.2
 - Flask-SQLAlchemy 2.5.1
 - greenlet         1.1.2
 - gunicorn         20.1.0
 - itsdangerous     2.0.1
 - Jinja2           3.0.3
 - MarkupSafe       2.0.1
 - pip              22.0.3
 - psycopg2         2.9.3
 - python-dotenv    0.19.2
 - setuptools       47.1.0
 - SQLAlchemy       1.4.31
 - Werkzeug         2.0.2
```

and as you can see i am using a virtual environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this

```
 app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = f"postgresql://{POSTGRES_USERNAME}:{POSTGRES_PASSWORD}@{POSTGRES_HOST}:{POSTGRES_PORT}/{POSTGRES_DBNAME}"
```

in your case it would be :

```
 app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = f"postgresql://postgres:password@localhost/quotes"
```

Answer (score 1):

the error is self explantory;

```
psycopg2.OperationalError: connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user " postgres"
```

i guess, there's an extra blank character in user name : `postgres`, so you should remove it in:

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:password@localhost/quotes'
```

Comment: Already fixed sorry about it .... the username for sb was kinda wrong cuz of white space .. fixed it .. :)